# os x yosemite with eclipse luna gwt not showing

Tags: gwt, osx-yosemite, eclipse-luna

I've just purchase MacBook Pro and upgrade OS X lion to yosemite. after upgrading install eclipse luna for the same version.
Now I need to use it for gwt development. I follow all the thing for installing it.

[image]

But not able to see google icon in toolbar for start my development.
[image]

Some forum I found I need latest java which is default not supplied by macos x anymore. So, I download and install it using below link.

> http://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp?locale=en

Is there anything else I missed...!?!

---

**Solved**

I just install latest jdk and problem solved

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Hope this is the real issue, if anyone know exact issue please respond this post for future user.